# Access XAML elements from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, user-interface

Is it possible to access xaml controls from not main class? I know there are other similar threads, but I am not sure they fit in my situation.

Previously, I was making my game with all content just one main class. But now, people recommended me changing this, because in my way, too many resources are consumed.

So, for starters, I made an Item class.

```
class classItem
{
public string ItemId;
public string ItemName;
public Image ItemImage;

public int InventoryPosition;

public Visibility ItemVisibility;

public string MouseEnter_ItemExamineText;
public string MouseClick_ItemExamineText;
public MediaPlayer ItemExamineVoice;

public string MouseEnter_ItemUseText;
public string MouseClick_ItemUseText;
public MediaPlayer ItemUseVoice;        


public string MouseEnter_ItemTakeText;
public string MouseClick_ItemTakeText;
public MediaPlayer ItemTakeVoice;

public string MouseEnter_ItemOpenCloseText;
public string MouseClick_ItemOpenCloseText;
public MediaPlayer ItemOpenCloseVoice;

public string MouseEnter_ItemMergeText;
public string MouseClick_ItemMergeText;
public MediaPlayer ItemMergeVoice;


public int ItemCurrentWidth;
public int[] ItemWidthResolutions = new int[6];


public int ItemCurrentHeight;
public int[] ItemHeightResolutions = new int[6];

public Thickness ItemCurrentMargin;
public Thickness[] ItemMarginResolutions = new Thickness[6];

// Generic Pre-set

public classItem()          
{
    ItemId = "";
    ItemName = "";
    ItemImage = null;
    ItemVisibility=Visibility.Hidden;

    InventoryPosition=0;

    MouseEnter_ItemExamineText = "";
    MouseClick_ItemExamineText = "";
    ItemExamineVoice = null;

    MouseEnter_ItemUseText = "";
    MouseClick_ItemUseText = "";
    ItemUseVoice = null;

    MouseEnter_ItemTakeText = "";
    MouseClick_ItemTakeText = "";
    ItemTakeVoice = null;

    MouseEnter_ItemOpenCloseText = "";
    MouseClick_ItemOpenCloseText = "";
    ItemOpenCloseVoice = null;

    MouseEnter_ItemMergeText = "";
    MouseClick_ItemMergeText = "";
    ItemMergeVoice = null;

    ItemWidthResolutions[0] = 1;
    ItemWidthResolutions[1] = 1;
    ItemWidthResolutions[2] = 1;
    ItemWidthResolutions[3] = 1;
    ItemWidthResolutions[4] = 1;
    ItemWidthResolutions[5] = 1;
    ItemCurrentWidth = ItemWidthResolutions[0];

    ItemHeightResolutions[0] = 1;
    ItemHeightResolutions[1] = 1;
    ItemHeightResolutions[2] = 1;
    ItemHeightResolutions[3] = 1;
    ItemHeightResolutions[4] = 1;
    ItemHeightResolutions[5] = 1;
    ItemCurrentHeight = ItemHeightResolutions[0];           

    ItemMarginResolutions[0] = new Thickness(-1000,-1000,0,0);
    ItemMarginResolutions[1] = new Thickness(-1000,-1000,0,0);
    ItemMarginResolutions[2] = new Thickness(-1000,-1000,0,0);
    ItemMarginResolutions[3] = new Thickness(-1000,-1000,0,0);
    ItemMarginResolutions[4] = new Thickness(-1000,-1000,0,0);
    ItemMarginResolutions[5] = new Thickness(-1000,-1000,0,0);
    ItemCurrentMargin = ItemMarginResolutions[0];               
    }

    // Item main class      

    public classItem(string Id, string Name, Image ItemImage,
    Visibility Vis, int InventoryPosition,
    string MouseEnter_ExamineText, string MouseClick_ExamineText,
    MediaPlayer ExamineVoice,     
    string MouseEnter_UseText, string MouseClick_UseText, 
    MediaPlayer UseVoice,
    string MouseEnter_TakeText, string MouseClick_TakeText,
    MediaPlayer  TakeVoice,
    string MouseEnter_OpenCloseText, string MouseClick_OpenCloseText,
    MediaPlayer OpenCloseVoice,
    string MouseEnter_MergeText, string MouseClick_MergeText,
    MediaPlayer MergeVoice, 
    int[] WidthResolutions, int[] HeightResolutions, 
    Thickness[]  MarginResolutions)

     {
     this.ItemId = Id;
     this.ItemName = Name;
     this.ItemImage = ItemImage;
     this.ItemVisibility = Vis;

     this.InventoryPosition = InventoryPosition;

     this.MouseEnter_ItemExamineText = MouseEnter_ExamineText;
     this.MouseClick_ItemExamineText = MouseClick_ExamineText;
     this.ItemExamineVoice = ExamineVoice;


     this.MouseEnter_ItemUseText  = MouseEnter_UseText;
     this.MouseClick_ItemUseText  = MouseClick_UseText;
     this.ItemUseVoice = UseVoice;      


     this.MouseEnter_ItemTakeText = MouseEnter_TakeText;
     this.MouseClick_ItemTakeText = MouseClick_TakeText;
     this.ItemTakeVoice = TakeVoice;


     this.MouseEnter_ItemOpenCloseText = MouseEnter_OpenCloseText;
     this.MouseClick_ItemOpenCloseText = MouseClick_OpenCloseText;
     this.ItemOpenCloseVoice = OpenCloseVoice;


     this.MouseEnter_ItemMergeText = MouseEnter_ItemMergeText;
     this.MouseClick_ItemMergeText = MouseClick_ItemMergeText;
     this.ItemMergeVoice = ItemMergeVoice;


     for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
     {
        this.ItemWidthResolutions[i]=WidthResolutions[i];
        this.ItemHeightResolutions[i]=HeightResolutions[i];
        this.ItemMarginResolutions[i]=MarginResolutions[i];
     }

     this.ItemCurrentWidth = this.ItemWidthResolutions[0];
     this.ItemCurrentHeight = this.ItemHeightResolutions[0];
     this.ItemCurrentMargin = this.ItemMarginResolutions[0];       
     }
}
```

What I want to do now - I want to make a sub-class (or whatever it is called) for each such item, and define its specific voids for it.

In my game, for the majority of actions, when you click on something, you get a text and a sound file plays. Also, there is sometimes a change in visibility of some images\objects.

So, the example of separate item class and voids can be:

```
        class Towel: classItem
        {
            void MouseEnter_ExamineItem()
            {
                lblTextOutput.Content=Towel.ItemExamineText;
                Towel.ItemExamineVoice.Play();
            }

            void MouseEnter_UseItem()
            {
                lblTextOutput.Content=Towel.ItemUseText;
                Towel.ItemUseVoice.Play();
            }       

        }
```

So, what lines I want to use in those voids,

There is one label "lblTextOutput" that is used to display relevant text.

```
lblTextOutput.Content="You took an item";
```

There are many sound files, I usually want to play one of them per void.

```
sndYouTookAnItem.Play();
```

And there are visual changes. For example:

```
imgBigBeautifulItem.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden;
```

All xaml elements are in file called "MainWindow.xaml".

But, I didn't find a way to access xaml elements from classes "classItem" or "classTowel". I tried using

```
MainWindow.lblTextOutput="BLAHBLAH"
```

but compiler still doesn't see them. How this can be solved? Or, if this approach is incorrect, how is better to do it?

Thank you,
Evgenie

Comment: Hi, could you format your code block, properly indent, to make it more readable?

Comment: Edited. Sorry for not making this from the beginning.

Comment: Maybe something like this should be added to this new class? 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }